# Extract group from groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Pandas DataFrame:

[image]

I have grouped it on the basis of date column present in it.

Now I am looping through min to max date and in inside loop I am trying to get dataframe for that date.

I am doing like this:

```
grouped_df = df.group_by('date')
for d in range(min_date, max_date + timedelta(days=1)):
     dated_df = grouped_df.get_group(d)
```

This is working fine for me but only for dates present in the range. For the dates like 2020/09/17 which is not present `dated_df = grouped_df.get_group(d)` this is throwing error.

Could someone help me in getting empty dataframe instead of error. I don't want to use try except.
Thanks.

Comment: happy to help, but first you need to provide a [mcve] just 5 rows of your data will do

Comment: Edited. Please check again. Thanks.

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to do a `try-except`, you can check the existence:

```
all_dates = set(df['date'])
for d in range(min_date, max_date + timedelta(days=1)):
     dated_df = grouped_df.get_group(d) if d in all_dates else None
```

Answer (score 2):

iterate over only the groups that `groupby` has created

```py
for d in grouped_df.groups.keys():
    dated_df = grouped_df.get_group(d)
```

However the groups.keys() doesn't necessarily preserve the order.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply iterate over the groups so that you don't have to worry about missing dates.

```
grouped_df = df.group_by('date')

for date, group in grouped_df:
    if date in range(min_date, max_date + timedelta(days=1)):
        dated_df = group
```

This is assuming that the min and max date is not over the whole range of `df['date']`. If the intent is to go over all the dates in the `df`, you don't need the if statement.